# Opencart: delete all missing items in the files when importing

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

Using the standard import / export module:

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=17

I need to delete all the products from the database that are not in the imported file. In the controller and in the model, I do not see the place where there is a check for the presence of goods in the database

Comment: Why don't you delete all products, then run the import?

Comment: This option will reset the settings of the modules by the recommended and orders or not?